# Reinstall of Ubuntu 11.10 failed and partitions nor hard disk not being recognized

Tags: 11.10, re-installation, boot-partition

I had Ubuntu 11.10 installed on my Samsung R519. It was working fine and I also had cinammon desktop and KDE installed, but eventually settled with KDE. I had my hard drive partitioned in 3 parts i think, one for boot and the others for file storage. So I would think that ubuntu would simply resintall on the boot partition since it was they who suggested I divide up my hard drive this way.

After a few months however upon bootup Ubuntu started warning me that there were disk errors. When I clicked check and fix, it would apparently never solve the problem. I never bothered to research the disk errors, but just kept ignoring them...until ubuntu eventually crashed on April 26. So i setup a USB install disk and proceeded to reinstall ubuntu and save my paritions and data. However at ''restoring previous installations'' ubuntu hung for several hours then reported that the installer crashed.

Now when I try to reinstall it is not detecting my partitions or the disk period for that matter. Even at BIOS setup my computer doesn't seem to detect my internal hard drive. It does detect my external harddrive though. So I know the problem is my internal HD. What can I do to get ubuntu or my pc to detect my drive again? Most of my personal data is backed up so if needs be I don't mind wiping the drive.

> > > > > Update - When I try to reboot from the disk, it says cannot read master boot record or sector 0.

Comment: Bin the faulty drive and install a new one.

Comment: Thats a possibility but I really dont want to do that just yet as there are one or two files that I was working on that didnt get backed up. So if theres anyway I can get the partitions or drive recognized without plugging it into eternally another computer, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my faulty hard drive was the main source of my problems. The BIOS was not even picking it up, so I unplugged it, turned on the computer, then shut down, reconnected it, at which point the computer picked it up. I then was able to reinstall Ubuntu 11.0 after a bit of of GRUB trouble.